# Drawing routes using user name in Rails 3 w/ devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise, ruby-on-rails-3

Given a one to many relationship between a user managed with devise and a "thing", my goal is to draw restful routes like:

```
http://host/username
http://host/username/things
http://host/username/things/1
...
```

I am aware of [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) in Rails routes, but I can't figure out how to apply it to a generic User model created and managed via devise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `scope` for this:

```
scope ":username", :as => "user" do
  resources :things
end
```

Combine this with `to_param` on the user model:

```
def to_param
  username
end
```

And you'll have routes such as `/username/things`. Be careful though, the username shouldn't contain any dots, forward slashes or standard URI characters. You may want to chuck a `parameterize` on the end of `username` to make sure.

Comment: great answer with the `to_param` combination.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `resource :user, path: ':id' do ... end`

Also don't forget to define `to_param` in your user modal & use `User.find_by_username(params[:id])` in your controller.