# Rails 3: Replace /users/username/something for /username/something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I already have a route to match `/username` for the users show page. However, when I add another action, for example: followers and following as below:

```
 resources :users, :only => [:show] do
    get :following, :followers
  end
```

I get the URL `/users/username/following` instead of `/username/following`.

How can I make all the `/users/username` URL's be matched as `/username/etc`.. ?

Here's my `/username` route:

```
match '/:id' => 'users#show', :constraints => { :id => /[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*/ }, :as => "user_profile"
```

thank you.

**Edit:**

I have fixed this by adding

```
match '/:id/following' => 'users#show/following', :as => "user_following"
match '/:id/followed' => 'users#show/following', :as => "user_followers"
```

**But I'm not sure if that's the best solution. What I'd really want is a default route that would match all `/:id/:action` to the appropriate action omitting the `/users`.**

Comment: Please check my answer in this question [Drawing routes using user name in Rails 3 w/ devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514533/drawing-routes-using-user-name-in-rails-3-w-devise) as I believe the two questions are identical.

Comment: Ryan, I'm not sure if I understand your answer. Can you please elaborate it so I can understand how it works? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by adding

```
match '/:id/following' => 'users#show/following', :as => "user_following"
match '/:id/followed' => 'users#show/following', :as => "user_followers"
```

But I'm not sure if that's the best solution. What I'd really want is a default route that would match all /:id/:action to the appropriate action omitting the /users.

Answer (score 0):

Near the bottom

```
match ':id/:action', :controller => :users
```