# Change devise route from ID to Username

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have tried using the post to change the routes to point at the username.  I know this is simple, but for some reason I can't compute it at the moment.  I have tried everything on the devise documentation page as well.

[Drawing username routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514533/drawing-routes-using-user-name-in-rails-3-w-devise)

I just want to have the routes layout to use the username instead of id and not have the users prefix. Like:

http://example.com/username

instead of

http://example.com/users/1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    username
  end
end
```

in your controller make

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
```

instead of

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

this will make your routes like http://example.com/users/username

to make what you want, you can do route like:

```
resources :users, :path => '' do
  # nested resources...
end
```

so, user_path(@user) will make url http://example.com/username
but It's not a good practice, cause it's not a REST. I advise you to leave urls like http://example.com/users/username

Comment: I get this result, the routes is pointing at the username now and I adjusted the UsersController#show with find_by_username, but still get--Couldn't find User with ID=DanReynolds

Comment: if the error is exact "Couldn't find User with ID=DanReynolds", than try to reload your server or something like this, because find_by_username doesn't raise NotFound error, it raises only evaluating nil error. or you can try something like @user = User.where(:username => params[:id]).first

Comment: how would you set up your routes if your using resources instead of matching each route?

Comment: If you want to ignore capital letters in username URL, `@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id].downcase)`