# Change devise route - id to username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise

How can I change the devise route from an id to username?

I want the path to be something like

```
http://www.site.com/users/username
```

instead of

```
http://www.site.com/users/id
```

---

In my view:

```
<span>posted by: <%= link_to( t.user.username, user_path( t.user.id ) ) %></span>
```

In my user model:

```
def to_param
    username
end
```

However, I am getting a routing error stating `uninitialized constant UsersController`.

I have these routes set up in routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users

root :to => 'tickets#index'

resources :users do
    resources :tickets
end

resources :tickets
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, search by `username` instead of by `id`:

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
```

Now, in your view, pass `username` instead of `id` to the `user_path` helper:

```
<%= link_to t.user.username, user_path(t.user.username) %>
```

---

- [Change devise route from ID to Username](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5698947/512904) – answer by [GearHead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462439/gearhead).

Comment: When I use this solution, I am able to go to /users/username but where in the view that the link is created, I get an error stating "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}" even though there is a 'show' action in the users controller.