# Rails - Devise - User Profile url with username on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I would like to get user profiles accessible from the URL: `root/user/(username)`

As of now I have it working with `root/user/(id)` but i want it to be more user friendly and shareable with the username in the URL.

This is how I currently have it set up

```
#user_controller.rb

class UserController < ApplicationController
  def profile
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end


#routes.rb

match 'user/:id' => 'user#profile'


#profile.html.erb

<h1><%= @user.firstname %>'s Profile</h1>
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to change out `:id` for `:username`. I've created the usernames in the user models from devise so I know that is working. But right now when I try to get usernames in the URL I get `Couldn't find User with id=username`.

Comment: I googled "rails devise username route" and found this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696302/change-devise-route-from-id-to-username

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your controller

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def profile
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
  end
end
```

Then the route

```
match 'user/:username' => 'user#profile'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Much Appreciated! I did not know about"User.find_by_username" where can i learn more about these kinds of commands? Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Try [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/FriendlyId/friendly_id). No need for any hacks in controller or model level.