# How to have example.com/username instead of example.com/user/1 in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

How can I amend the routing from `http://localhost:3000/profiles/1` to `http://localhost:3000/myusername` ?

I have a Profile model with the following table:

```
def self.up
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.text :interest

      t.timestamps
    end
 end
```

And my `routes.rb` file:

```
  resources :profiles
```

I have looked at similar answers dealing with [to_param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611649/ruby-on-rails-routing-matching-username), [devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696302/change-devise-route-from-id-to-username) or [nested loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514533/drawing-routes-using-user-name-in-rails-3-w-devise)s or even [an example in Rails 2.3](http://garrickvanburen.com/archive/using-names-in-rails-routes-instead-of-ids), but i couldn't find a way that works.

What changes should I make to the `profile/view/show.html.erb`, `routes.rb` and `model/profile.rb` (if any) to amend the routing from `http://localhost:3000/profiles/1` to `http://localhost:3000/username`? I'm learning from the basics, hence I rather not use any gems or plugins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want use usernames instead of IDs try [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem.

If you want to do it by yourself, the easiest way is to override method to_param in our model to return username, and then search in your controller by username.

In model:

```
def to_param
  username
end
```

In controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
end
```

In routes.rb file:

```
  match '/:id' => 'profiles#show'
```

Comment: @Egor: Thanks! Yes, that would be helpful and I can use a gem or even devise. But i'm trying to learn and hence do from the basics without any gems.

Comment: You can override method to_param in our model to return username, and then search in your controller by username.
I update the answer with details.

Comment: Thanks Egor! This however gives me http://localhost:3000/profile/username and not yet, http://localhost:3000/username. I guess, i'll need to amend the routes.rb as well?

Comment: You really want localhost:3000/username? It may be dangerous and confusing for your users. For example if someone take name like "articles", "posts", or "profile". If you still want localhost:3000/username you may need make some complicated routes or even hack Rails engine.

Comment: In routes you can write: match ":id" => "users#show". This make localhost:3000/username works fine.

Comment: Hi @Egor: Many thanks for your help! I did this in routes.rb:   match '/:id' => 'profiles#show'. Now the url looks pretty like facebook/twitter or many other sites in the format of site.com/username :)

Comment: That's great. Worked for me as well. Just one thing... now other URLs like about, signup, contact and login don't work for me.

Comment: Moving the route for the username below the other pages fixes it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param